# Exception when trying to send a message to firebase server

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can you please find out what is wrong with this code?

```
public class NewMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
String mDisplayName = "John";
EditText mNewMessageField;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final EditText mNewMessageField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newMessageText);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_message);
    ImageButton mSendButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
    mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            sendMessage();
            finish();
        }
    });
}

private void sendMessage(){
    mDatabaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    String input = mNewMessageField.getText().toString();
    SingleMessage singleMessage = new SingleMessage(input, mDisplayName);
    mDatabaseReference.child("messages").push().setValue(singleMessage);
}
```

}

Immediately after I press the send button, the app stops working and I get this error message:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                at com.***.NewMessageActivity.sendMessage(NewMessageActivity.java:42)
>                                                                                at com.***.NewMessageActivity.access$000(NewMessageActivity.java:14)
>                                                                                at com.***.NewMessageActivity$1.onClick(NewMessageActivity.java:33)
>                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4209)
>                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17457)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5341)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:929)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
>                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   11-28 20:05:51.566 508-527/? E/AppErrorDialog: Failed to get ILowStorageHandle instance

Comment: what is written on line 14?

Comment: public class NewMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Comment: are u connected to firebase?

Comment: Yes. I can sign in perfectly well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `setContentView(`) **before** you search for the `EditText` widget.  You also must use the instance of `mNewMessageField` declared at package level.  Don't declare a new instance in `onCreate()`.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_message);
mNewMessageField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newMessageText);  // <= CHANGED
if (mNewMessageField == null) {
    System.out.println("mNewMessageField is NULL");
}
```

To get more clues, add this debug output:

```
private void sendMessage(){
    mDatabaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    if (mNewMessageField == null) {
        System.out.println("mNewMessageField is NULL");
    }
    Editable ed = mNewMessageField.getText();

    if (ed == null) {
        System.out.println("Editable is NULL");
    }
    String input = mNewMessageField.getText().toString();
    System.out.println("input=" + input);

    SingleMessage singleMessage = new SingleMessage(input, mDisplayName);
    mDatabaseReference.child("messages").push().setValue(singleMessage);
}
```

Comment: nice catch, +1!

Comment: Thanks. I changed the code as you suggested, but the problem still exists. :(

Comment: @Mohsen: Check your `activity_new_message` layout to confirm the ID on the `EditText` is `newMessageText`.

Comment: @Bob Thank you. I checked it, and it seems that there is no problem with that. The ID indeed is "newMessageText".

Comment: @Mohsen: Add the check shown in my update, run and look at the logcat output to see if `nNewMessageField` is null.  If it is, there is still some problem with the widget ID in the layout, or you are looking at the wrong layout file.

Comment: I really appreciate the time you are spending on this. I did what you asked, and didn't get the "mNewMessageField is NULL" message in logcat. It seems that the mNewMessageField is not null.

Comment: @Mohsen:  I debug with log messages rather than the debugger.  If you prefer the debugger, step through the code of `sendMessage()`. Otherwise, update `sendMessage()` with the debug output I added to my answer and run again.

Comment: @Mohsen:  Okay.  I see the mistake and updated my answer.  You are declaring a second instance of `mNewMessage` in `onCreate()` so the one used in `sendMessage()` is null.  Make the change shown in my updated answer.

Comment: YES! Thank you very very much! I can't believe I made such a stupid mistake!